# CASE Statement to select a particular value if value exists in another table

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I have a requirement where I need to order the records in the result set cursor returned by a stored procedure in a particular order. For example, assume that the SP returned 10 records.The result contains a field named FLD1. The records whose FLD1 value is present in another table must be placed at the top of the result set. That is the records whose FLD1 value returns results when used in a query like `SELECT * FROM RESULTS WHERE FLD1 IN (SELECT FLD2 FROM TABLE2)` must be placed at the top of the result set and the records which do not return any records must come afterward.

The approach I am following is to first select the records which satisfy the condition `FLD1 IN (SELECT FLD2 FROM TABLE2)` and assign a seq.no 1 and store the results in a temp table. Then select the records which do not satisfy the condition `FLD1 IN (SELECT FLD2 FROM TABLE2)` and assign them a sequence 2. Finally, merge the results and open a result cursor at the end of the SP ordering by the Sequence number.

Please suggest any better approach if you know of one. I was thinking of using a CASE statement like `CASE WHEN FLD1 IN (SELECT FLD2 FROM TABLE2) THEN "1" ELSE "2"`. But this does not seem to work in DB2.

Comment: Can you provide some code and test cases. Then tell us what is working and what is wrong with the ones that don't work?

Answer (score 2):

simply like this :

```
select case when t2.fld2 is not null then 1 else 2 end as seq, t1.*
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.fld1=t2.fld2
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

So I seemed to have found the answer.

The trick is to use case as below:

```
CASE 
  WHEN (SELECT T41SBI FROM TC401F 
        WHERE T40BID = TC401F.T41SBI) IS NOT NULL THEN '1' 
  ELSE '2' 
END AS SEQ,
```

and finally order by SEQ field. If somebody could validate this , that would be great

Comment: This _might_ run the query for every row if placed in the `SELECT` clause.  doing it as a join (assuming the rows are unique, or doing something to ensure uniqueness) as in Esperento57's answer _may_ yield better results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `IN` predicate is not valid in the `CASE` statement.

This works for me, as long as the assumptions are correct:

```
create table test1
  (field1 Char(25),
   field2 Char(5));

create table test2
  (field1 Char(5),
   descrip Char(25));

insert into test1
  values  ('This is line 1', 'OK'),
          ('This is line 2', 'FAIL'),
          ('This is line 3', 'OK'),
          ('This is line 4', 'FAIL');

insert into test2
  values ('OK', 'This is a valid code');

select field1, 
       field2,
       case
         when (select field2 from test2 
               where a.field2 = field1) is not null then '1'
         else '2'
       end seq
  from test1 a
  order by 3, 1;
```

The results are:

```
FIELD1          FIELD2  SEQ
==============  ======  ===
This is line 1   OK      1
This is line 3   OK      1
This is line 2   FAIL    2
This is line 4   FAIL    2
```